# Getting user input for an array

Tags: c++

I try to create an array. The size of it depends on the user's input. But how can I do it? or should I use string or vector instead?

I am new to C++. When I googled the problem, I still didn't get it. I tried the following code but it was not working.

```
const int t;
cin >>t;
double myarrary[t]={};
```

but my friends code works.

```
cin >> num;
int px[num]={};
```

Thank you

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that introduces you to the C++ library, and the `std::vector` template, and all will be explained. "Googling" is not a very good way to learn C++. The best way to do so is [by learning from a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable length arrays like `double myarrary[t]` where `t` is a run-time value are a C feature. It is not in C++ standard, but some compilers do support that.

Use `std::vector` for portability.

Comment: but i set t as constant. Shouldn't it be treated as a constant?

Comment: @Www Working on some compilers doesn’t mean that you should write such code. Conformance to the standard does.

Comment: @Www How can it be a constant if you're reading user input into it after it was declared? By definition, the value of a `const` variable has to be initialized when it is declared and can't change after that. Also, array sizes need to be *compile-time* constants (the value is known during compile time), not just constant after the declaration.

Comment: @L.F. Conformance to the standard doesn't necessarily mean the code is good either.

Comment: @FeiXiang Oh yes! Definitely! It was only meant to be a comparison, but I worded it too ambiguously ...